# Workflow not starting on PWA

Tags: workflow, splistitem, tasks, project-server

I have a problem with workflow on PWA.

I created a simple workflow that will send e-mail when a task is assigned to a particular person by Project Manager using PWA Schedule page. The problem is that workflow is not even starting when new items are added to list.

[image: Workflow properties from SharePoint Designer]

[image: Workflow itself]

Any ideas?

Comment: One more important note is that workflow is working correctly when its started manually.

Answer (score 0):

I find out that the workflow is running under System Account which gets System.UnauthorizedAccessException. Now the main problem is defining what System Account is.